# how to extract string from json within a json in java

Tags: java, android

I have a android project in which I tried to read and store information from json file. But it's not straightforward because I don't know how to extract string from this type of json. From the json file, it seems like it's a json inside a json? Following is the json formatted data

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "some information",
    "2. Symbol": "something",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "time",
    "4. Interval": "1min",
    "5. Output Size": "Compact",
    "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
             }
}
```

I have tried the following but it does not seem to work

```
try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(message);
            JSONArray Jarray  = object.getJSONArray("Meta Data");

            for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray a = Jasonobject.getJSONArray("1. Information");
                Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: ");

            }
}catch{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I debugged my application I got following message in console

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for Meta Data
```

What I am trying to do is extract "something","some information" into variables.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? Is there a better way and if so could you please share the code snippet? Thanks

Comment: There are no arrays in that JSON.

Comment: That is not even valid JSON.